# PDO SQlite extension / PDOStatement bug?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

we currently encounter a strange bug using PDO and an SQLite in memory database.

Here is a peace of code to reproduce the problem.

**Execute the following PHP code**

```
<?php 

// Gets a PDO reference with in memory SQLite (i.e using the 'sqlite::memory:' dsn)
$pdo = new \PDO('sqlite::memory:', 'sa', '');

$pdo->exec(
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scheduled_task' . 
    '(' .
        'id                                          INTEGER         NOT NULL,' .
        'date_and_time                               INTEGER         NOT NULL,' . 
        'task_class                                  VARCHAR(256)    NOT NULL,' .
        'task_parameters                             VARCHAR(1024)   NOT NULL' .
    ')'
);

// Just a statement to count rows in our table
$pdoStatementCount = $pdo->prepare('select count(*) from scheduled_task');

// At first ensure our table is empty
$pdoStatementCount->execute();
var_dump('At beginning table has size \'' . intval($pdoStatementCount->fetchColumn()) . '\'.');

// Insert 2 rows inside our table
$pdoStatementInsert = $pdo->prepare(
    'insert into scheduled_task(id, task_class, date_and_time, task_parameters) values(?,?,?,?)'
);
$pdoStatementInsert->execute([1, 'tk1', '2015-01-01', '{}']);
$pdoStatementInsert->execute([2, 'tk2', '2015-01-02', '{}']);

// Ensure the 2 rows were inserted
$pdoStatementCount->execute();
var_dump('Then table has size \'' . intval($pdoStatementCount->fetchColumn()) . '\'.');

// Now create a statement to select only the first row
$pdoStatementSelect1 = $pdo->query('select * from scheduled_task where date_and_time < \'2015-01-02\'');

// Here it seems their is a bug with the Iterator associated to the PDO Statement
foreach($pdoStatementSelect1 as $row) {
    var_dump($row['id']);

    // Inserts a new row inside our table
    $pdoStatementInsert = $pdo->prepare(
        'insert into scheduled_task(id, task_class, date_and_time, task_parameters) values(?,?,?,?)'
    );
    if($pdoStatementInsert->execute([3, 'tk3', '2015-01-01', '{}']) === false)  {
        var_dump('Fail inserting row in loop !');
        var_dump($pdoStatementInsert->errorCode());
        var_dump($pdoStatementInsert->errorInfo());
    }

    // Deletes the first row
    $pdo->query('delete from scheduled_task where id = ' . $row['id']);
}

// This fails with SQLite, we should have 2 rows inside our table here
$pdoStatementCount->execute();
var_dump('At the end table has size \'' . intval($pdoStatementCount->fetchColumn()) . '\'.');
```

**The output of this test is the following.**

```
string(32) "At beginning table has size '0'."
string(24) "Then table has size '2'."
string(1) "1"
string(1) "3"
string(30) "At the end table has size '1'."
```

**Conclusion, bug in PDO SQLite ?**

Please note that our foreach loop is executed 2 times instead of one. So it seems the PDOStatement object used in our loop is updated (don't know how) because we inserted a new row inside our loop.

If we change our PDO instance to use MySQL then it works, so I think this bug is related to SQLite only.

Although if I change the insert instruction placed inside the loop to this (i.e the date does not match with our select) then it works.

```
$pdoStatementInsert->execute([3, 'tk3', '2015-01-02', '{}'])
```

So its like of the SQLite PDOStatement were doing a new select query transparently...

Do you know why we encounter this behavior ? Do you think its normal ? If not do we have to report it at https://bugs.php.ne ?

**FINAL ANSWER - THIS IS NOT A BUG**
See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72267&edit=2
Thanks for your help !

Thanks.

Comment: Do you clear the table before you re-run the test? It would appear that the row with id 3 may still exist.

Comment: Yes I 100% sure my table is empty at the beginning. I updated my code sample so that its only one PHP script. So anybody can simply execute the script to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You're modifying your resultset whilst reading it so presumably SQLite's internal pointers are getting confused. It's more an unsupported action than a bug. Is this something you really need to do or is it just an abstract question?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response,"You're modifying your resultset whilst reading it".I do not agree because the PDOStatement used to select is not the same as the one used to insert.So IMO the 2 statements should be isolated,a statement should not have any effect on the other."Is this something you really need to do or is it just an abstract question?",both :-),  in fact I think this behavior should definlty be considered to be a bug or at least be clearly documented.We're lucky to see this with SQLite not in production,cannot imagine the consequences on a large production DB... Do U Agree ?

Comment: "a statement should not have any effect on the other" Both statements use the same _connection_ so they take place in the same _transaction_. Could you modify the logic to use `$results = $stmt->fetchAll(); foreach ($results as $row) { ...`? That way you iterate on a fixed array, not a variable resultset.

Comment: Thanks, yes it works with a fetchAll(). In fact here I do not want to make my code work but want to be sure the behavior on the PDOStatement is the expected behavior. As explained in the official PHP documentation a PDOStatement "Represents a prepared statement and, after the statement is executed, an associated result set." Si after statement execution I would expect my PDOStatement to "embedded" a result set which is "isolated" (and so which should not be modified if not touched directly with its functions). Do you agree with this ?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, see my update on the post, this is "expected" behavior and is not a PDO bug.